# Error handling when i cannot use exceptions(failwith, try-finally, raise etc.) or Options

Tags: f#

I have this assignment where i have to handle a error but with some limitations, i cannot use exceptions and Options. So lets say i have the following piece of code:

```
let tryWithIndex arr i =
    if ((Array.length arr)-1 > i) then
        arr.[i]
    else
        ???
```

My problem is that i dont know how to specify a "null" kind of value in the else statement, another thing is that it has to be a  'a[]  input, so e.g. if it was a int[] i would just be able to return -99999, like thats a really bad idea, because this assignment is stupid, but thats the kind of primitive solution i am looking for, just in a generic manner.

So my question is, how do i return a "default" value with type 'a ??

Comment: Unchecked.defaultof<int>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal, functional way to do this would be to return a Maybe, which in F# is called `option`. If you can't use the built-in `option`, you could define your own Maybe, which would be equivalent:

```
type Maybe<'a> = Just of 'a | Nothing
```

That's probably cheating, but you can also use Either, defined by

```
type Either<'a, 'b> = Left of 'a | Right of 'b
```

Try to write your function so that it has the type

```
'a [] -> int -> Either<string,'a>
```

Since this is an assignment, I'll leave the rest as an exercise :)

Comment: Yeah i like your suggestion. My method just needs to return 'a  so it cannot return my own Either. But your suggestion of implementing a option your self works, and answers my question so i will accept your answer :). I did use the  Unchecked.defaultof<'a> though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing would be to first question the "I cant use Options".
But lets pretend it is so. In order to have a better way to handle that could be via callbacks.

```
let tryWithIndex (callback: Unit -> 'T) (arr: [] 'T) i =
    if ((Array.length arr)-1 > i) then
        arr.[i]
    else
        callback()
```

and on your call site you could do

```
let intArr : [] = ...
let r = tryWithIndex (fun () -> -9999) intArr 66
```